# How do I set up my react-hot-loader to react to changes instantly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am building a very simple, 'Hello World' style server using MongoDB, React, Babel, Node.js, Webpack, Express, and a couple other software modules.  I am able to build, compile, and run said server, but hot-loader never updates the DOM.  I get no errors in my terminal and my server otherwise runs fine, but in my browser console I get the following:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

at Object../node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true (bundle.js:1197:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:726:30)
at fn (bundle.js:101:20)
at Object.0 (bundle.js:1287:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:726:30)
at bundle.js:793:37
at bundle.js:796:10
```

My non-dev dependencies associated with hot-loader and listed in my **package.json** are the following (Outdated versions were required for the server I'm making, although I was never told why):

-Node: 13.12.0

-NPM: 6.14.4

-@hot-loader/react-dom: 16.13.0

-Express: 4.17.1

-MongoDB: 3.5.5

-React: 16.13.1

-React-DOM: 16.13.1

-React-hot-loader: 4.12.2

The loader exports my module const (HelloWorld), but only once and never updates it if I change the text in any way.
Is there a simple mistake I'm making?  I would be happy to provide more code if needed.

My **HelloWorld.js**, responsible for the export:

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader'
import React from 'react'

const HelloWorld = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
      )
}

export default hot(module)(HelloWorld)
```

Here is my **main.js**, responsible for rendering elements in the root:

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader'
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld'


render(<HelloWorld/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

What should I include in HelloWorld or Main that allows my hot-loader to update my page in real time as quickly as possible?  Thank you for your time and I apologize if my question is disorderly or confusing.  I often have trouble speaking concisely.

Comment: If you want to simplify things you may want to ditch Webpack/hot-loader altogether and (_not an advert_) use something like [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#overview) which will manage this without too much configuration for React. I've been using it for a year now and it is effortless, and fast.

Comment: @Andy The build tool you linked looks fantastic and I appreciate the recommendation.  Unfortunately, I don't think I'll be allowed to ditch Webpack or hot-loader as I was specifically told to use them.  I would like to attempt using Vite in my future projects.